# How do I get the NetworkName(SSID) of the currently connected network in Windows Store Apps (C#)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to get the NetworkName (SSID) fo the current network connection in a windows store app. I see NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetNetworkNames(), but how can there be multiple names? Is there another way to get the SSID?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The new Microsoft API WinRT will not allow you to list SSIDs
>   regardless of user permissions.  While it can be done with Win32, it
>   cannot be done with WinRT.  Remember that an App can't enter the Store
>   unless it is exclusively WinRT.  This means that there won't be any
>   advanced WiFi analysis Apps in the Windows 8 store - ever.

From : [You can't list SSIDs with WinRT](http://www.acumen-corp.com/Blog/tabid/298/entryid/65/You-cant-list-SSIDs-with-WinRT.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Using the library. It resulted to be quite easy to work with the classes provided:

//First I had to create a WlanClient obhect

wlan = new WlanClient();

//And then I can get the list of the SSIDs the PC is connected to with this code:

Collection<String> connectedSsids = new Collection<string>();

        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanInterface in wlan.Interfaces)
        {
            Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = wlanInterface.CurrentConnection.wlanAssociationAttributes.dot11Ssid;
            connectedSsids.Add(new String(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ssid.SSID,0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength)));
        }
```